# Best laptop cooling pad (to protect your lap)

Tags: laptop, cooling

I'm looking for laptop cooling pad to protect my laptop from getting too hot and (more importantly to me) to protect my lap from the heat when I'm working with the laptop on my lap.

I'm currently looking at the "Targus Lap Chill Mat":  http://www.targus.com/us/product_details.aspx?sku=AWE55US.
 It is USB-powered, contains a couple fans, and looks like it might do a good job of protecting your lap from the heat.

Does anyone recommend this or suggest another that might be better?  Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:**

Thanks for the suggestions!

Side note:  I came across a pretty sweet mat - it's the new "Logitech Lapdesk N700".  It's looks very comfortable and includes built-in speakers!  It's a bit too much $$ for what I'm looking to spend.  :-) 
http://www.pcworld.com/article/185995/logitechs_new_lapdesk_n700_cools_and_plays_music.html

Comment: How large is your laptop?

Comment: It's a Dell Latitude D620 laptop, and it has a 14-inch widescreen.

Comment: Isn't it false advertising to call these things "laptops"?

Comment: Also.. there are ways to limit your max CPU speed; this will often prevent the machine from running at a dangerous temperature, and also save power, and still let it run quickly enough to get the job done.  I usually have my 2.4GHz Turion64 processor scaled down to 800MHz; as such I rarely find that it's noticeably slow.  This might be helpful if you don't want to carry a "desk" around with you at all times 8'\

Comment: Here's an interesting article comparing 5 passive (non powered) options: http://online.wsj.com/article/SB116433227010031654.html?mod=Catalog+Critic - I'm still holding out for the best one that doubles as a sleeve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up ordering the Targus mat that I mentioned above. I like that it lifts the laptop up off your lap (or whatever surface you have it on) and then vents the hot air out the sides, as opposed to venting the air directly down onto your lap, which some of the ones that I saw appear to do.

Answer (score 4):

NewEgg has a huge selection (100+) of laptop cooling pads. Out of all of those, the highest-rated pad is the [ZALMAN Ultra Quiet Notebook Cooler](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834998051). It's aluminum, powered by USB, and includes two extra USB ports (which is really nice).

[See all of NewEgg's coolers by popularity.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2030260319%201276817102&bop=And&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&ActiveSearchResult=True&Order=RATING)

I currently am using the [Antec Notebook Cooler](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834999850), and it's okay. It's powered by USB and plugs into the side of the cooler. The plug shorted out, and I had to open up the cooler and solder the power cord to the circuit board. When this one finally dies, I'll be getting a nicer one.

Comment: I didn't think to check NewEgg.  I'll take a look at your link!  (BTW, I like to upvote answers that I find useful, but I'll have to wait to upvote yours until I have enough reputation points to do so.)  :)

Comment: @bporter Yeah, I always run to NewEgg - I should ask them for a  stipend for the amount of advertising I do for them!

Comment: I have the same problem with the Antec Cooler. I just put aluminum foil in the plug, and it works, generally...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [Notepal Infinite](http://forum.notebookreview.com/accessories/162820-cooler-master-notepal-infinite-review-lots-pics-d.html).

[image]

I have one, and what I like is that it's not only blowing air to specific places, but blowing it rather all over the surface, keeping it cool.

So it won't cool down that much better your CPU or GPU if you have already individual fans for them (no external cooler can be as effective as the internal fans, of course), but it will instead keep all the bottom cooler, which is good for the other parts like hard drive, ram, or battery.

Note however that this cooler can be a bit noisy on full speed, some people can be disturbed by that.

Answer (score 1):

The [Philips Notebook sleeve with HeatProtect](http://www.usa.philips.com/c/notebook-and-ipad-accessoires/13.3-inch-with-heatprotect-sle3300fn_27/prd/) looks interesting - as it is a laptop sleeve combined with heat-dissipating surface:

[image]

Only negatives I've read is that it doesn't hold your laptop snugly on an angle, so it can slide off when working on your lap.

Curious if anyone has seen any other similar product?  I'd love to have a sleeve that effectively works as a (passive) cooling surface

Comment: Bought this and can confirm that the laptop definitely slides off on an angle.  A couple pieces of velcro may help with this.  It does seem to dissipate some heat though, better than a 'normal' sleeve.

Answer (score 0):

The [Lapinator](http://www.lapinator.com/index.php) (yeah, terrible name) also looks interesting (and lightweight):
[image]

Features 3M Thinsulate material for heat dissipation, although it looks like they suggest using those two plastic risers to increase airflow