# HP Pavilion DV4 1211 hard disk hitting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cooling, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion DV4 1211 laptop.

I have a problem with my hard disk ( which is 320 GB), when I use laptop in 30 min or more than hard disk temperature going to 60°+ Celsius.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: As a test, stand the laptop up on its side to get more airflow and see if the temp drops at all.

Answer (score 0):

Laptops - specially HP's - usually get hotter than desktops because they can't exhaust air as efficiently.

60 what?

- **Celsius** - a bit too hot on some people standards, you probably should be more careful with what surface the laptop is on - avoid glass, wool and other heat insulators. Look for a [laptop cooler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laptop_cooler). Also, check the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/158390/suggestions-on-keeping-laptop-cool) question on how to keep your laptop cool.
- **Fahrenheit** - a bit too cold, probably shouldn't use the laptop outside when it's snowing.
- **Kelvin** - you should contact NASA.